# Join 3 lists using JoinView

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list

This is regarding SharePoint 2007, I have 3 list in a site called "A", "B", "C".

I have combined this 3 lists in one and created a new list called "D" using SharePoint Designer 2007.

Now showed the List "D" fields or data on webpart in designer but it's not coming up as I expected.

I'm giving here as an example of 3 list.
[image]

After joining this 3 lists using JoinView in Designer, result showing up as given below.
[image]

And I need to show these 3 list fields or data as given below.[image]

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, relationship between List B and List C should be based on **Corrective Action no** column of List B not Issue ID.

1. Update List C by adding **Corrective Action no** from List B and removing Issue ID.
2. Create a linked Data Source say "DS1" with List B and List C.
3. Create another linked data source with List A and DS1...name it as DS2
4. Use DS2 as the data source of your DVWP.

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Avijit.

I tried but problem couldn't be solved.
As list "A" is parent and rest list is child.so once I drag the fields on webpart of DS2 which contain the field of List "A" as well and then select JoinView, and followed the steps as given here in this link:  can you please follow this link so that you can better understand the problem.

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15258.sharepoint-2010-how-to-link-two-list-and-create-a-combine-view.aspx